# My bootstrap modal shows up fine, however the background doesn't fade

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Any ideas, why my background does not fade when this modal appears?

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" style="" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="position: relative;  top: 137px;width:1000px;height:350px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
<div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <table id="foobar" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered small">
                            <thead>
                                <th style="width:100px;">Host ID</th>
                                <th style="width:100px;">col 2</th>
                                <th style="width:100px;">col 3</th>
                                <th>col 4</th>
                                <th>col 5</th>
                                <th>col 6</th>
                                <th>col 7</th>
                                <th>col 8</th>
                                <th>col 9</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: i assume you don't have the css. .modal-backdrop.in {
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}

Comment: I have the standard bootstrap css loaded.  Otherwise the modal, wouldn't appear correctly.

Comment: On all browsers or just one particular one?  I've had odd results with older versions of IE.

Comment: All browsers....seems to be something with my code.

Comment: Your markup validates.  Which release of Bootstrap?

Comment: The latest.  So I see the modal-backdrop div that gets created in the code.  However it doesn't take up the whole screen.  It seems to have no positioning.

Comment: So, I'm on ver. 3.3.1.   There seems to be an issue with this version where CSS definitinon is missing.  UPgraded to 3.3.4 and I'm good now.  Thanks @JECarterII That pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Awesome.  Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3.3.1 has a bug in the CSS.  3.3.2 Fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Model works fine in this **[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/y55uyhfx/)**
Try placing your CSS Bootstrap link last... below any of your custom CSS links.
To see if it is a custom CSS file is creating this issue for you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks @AngularJR  There was a bug in 3.3.1 that was causing my issue.

Comment: Great you have it sorted.